# How to change state in one component and listen to it in another Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have two components. In one of the I'm commiting change to the store on click. In another I want to listen to this change and react to it.

If I look at my Vuex store my commit is working on every click but I'm not sure how to listen for it in another component.

Component A

```
methods: {
        openMenu() {
            this.open = !this.open;
            this.$store.commit('OPEN_MENU', this.open);
        }
    }

<button @click="openMenu"></button>
```

In my Component B I tried binding to computed property but it only runs once, when component is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create vuex getter for 'open'
2. Create the computed property in component B:

> ```
> computed: {
>   open () {
>     return this.$store.getters.open
>   }
> }
> ```

3. Use this.open in script or template

Comment: Here is my getter `const sideNavIsVisible = (state, status) => {
    return state.open;
};` But how do I keep it up to date with my state? Right now it returns initial value from state.

Comment: create: `mutations: {
    setOpen(state, payload) {
      state.open = payload
    }
  }`, and use this mutation to change state like `this.$store.commit('setOpen', someValue)`